# how to load a div only without loading all page files with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this `AJAX` code, where it helps to insert some data into `MySQL`, and stay in the same page:

```
$(function(){
  $("#form1").on("submit", function (e){
      console.log("Form is submitted");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#form1').serialize() + "&insert=yes",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        alert($('#form1').serialize());
      } //<--------------------------------------- You missed this
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    //location.reload();
  });
  $("#insert").on("click", function (e){
      console.log("Insert Key is clicked");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#form1').serialize() + "&insert=yes",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        alert($('#form1').serialize());
      } //<--------------------------------------- You missed this
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

I need to remove this line:

```
location.reload();
```

And replace it with a code that help me to refresh a `div` where I have an `HTML Table` that shows me, data inserted at the moment. Here is the code of this `div`:

```
<div id="section2">
  <table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5" bgcolor="#666666">المبيعات</th>
    </tr>

      <th width="15%">النوع</th>
      <th width="35%">Alfa/Touch</th>
      <th width="25%">المبلغ</th>
      <th width="25%">رقم الفاتورة (OMT, Alfa ...)</th>
      <th width="25%">العملة</th>
    <form name="insertForm" action="insert.php" method="post" id="form1">

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <select id="selectW" name="type">
            <option value="لم يتم التحديد">اختر النوع</option>
            <option value="دولارات">دولارات</option>
            <option value="أيام + دولارات">أيام + دولارات</option>
            <option value="بطاقات">بطاقات</option>
            <option value="هواتف">هواتف</option>
            <option value="اكسسوارات">اكسسوارات</option>
            <option value="تسديد فواتير">تسديد فواتير</option>
          </select>
          <!--<select>
          <?php foreach($result5 as $rows){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?>"><?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>-->
          </td>
        <td align="center"><select id="select_at" name="alfa_touch">
            <option value="غير محدد">Not Required</option>
            <option value="Alfa">Alfa</option>
            <option value="Touch">Touch</option></select></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="pay" name="pay"/></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="facture" name="facture" placeholder="في حال دفع الفواتير عبر omt"/></td>
        <td align="center"><select id="select" name="currency">
            <option value="9">ليرة</option>
            <option value="10">دولار</option>
            </select></td>

        <td align="center"><input type="submit" id="insert" name="insert" value="اضافة" />

      </td>

      </tr>
      </form>   
      <?php
        $sum = 0;
        $selectAll = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date_now = :date ORDER BY date_now DESC, time_now DESC";
        $stmtAll=$conn->prepare($selectAll);
        $stmtAll->bindValue(':date', date("y-m-d"));
        $execAll=$stmtAll->execute();
        $result=$stmtAll->fetchAll();
      ?>
      <?php foreach($result as $rows){
          $sum = $sum + $rows['pay'];
          //var_Dump($rows) ?>
    <tr>
      <td height="30" align="center"><?php echo $rows['type'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['provider'] ?></td>
      <td align="center" dir="ltr"><?php echo (number_format($rows['pay'], 0, ',', ' ')). ' L.L'?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['facture'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><form action='delete.php' method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" />
          <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('هل أنت متأكد؟')" name="delete_sales" value="" />
        </form></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="#666666">المجموع</th>
    <td dir="ltr" bgcolor="#666666" align="center"><?php
        echo ($sum = number_format($sum, 0, ',', ' ')). ' L.L';
      ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I tried some stackoverflow answered question about something called append, but nothing works (no errors shown in console).

Is their any code that let me load only this div every time I add data, without reloading all the page with all external files included in it like .css and other .js files ?

Comment: First..  It does seem `.append()` will do what you need.  Secondly to test the `append()`  don't just paste all of your code at once.  Insert a line at a time.  And to be safe keep the append all on a single line.  This will help narrow where your issue is.

Comment: What I need so ? I need help

Comment: See my answer for an explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing your question, I could say this would probably work out for you:

```
$("#insert").on("click", function (e){
  $this = $(this)
  $.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#form1').serialize() + "&insert=yes",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $this.closest("tr").after('<td height="30" align="center">' + 
        $('[name=""]').val() + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center">' + $('[name="selectW"]').val() + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center" dir="ltr">' + $('[name="alfa_touch"]').val() + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center">' + $('[name="pay"]').val() + '</td>' +
        '<td align="center"><form action="delete.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="" /><input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onclick="return confirm(\'هل أنت متأكد؟\')" name="delete_sales" value="" /></form></td>');
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  // location.reload(); // remove this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this .. eventually ..

```
$(function(){
$("#form1").on("submit", function (e){
  console.log("Form is submitted");
$.ajax({
  url: 'insert.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: $('#form1').serialize() + "&insert=yes",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert($('#form1').serialize());
  } //<--------------------------------------- You missed this
});

e.preventDefault();
//location.reload();
});
$("#insert").on("click", function (e){
  console.log("Insert Key is clicked");
$.ajax({
  url: 'insert.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: $('#form1').serialize() + "&insert=yes",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert($('#form1').serialize());
  } //<--------------------------------------- You missed this
});

e.preventDefault();
$('#YourDivId').append('<div id="section2"><table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"><tr><th colspan="5" bgcolor="#666666">المبيعات</th></tr><th width="15%">النوع</th><th width="35%">Alfa/Touch</th><th width="25%">المبلغ</th><th width="25%">رقم الفاتورة (OMT, Alfa ...)</th><th width="25%">العملة</th><form name="insertForm" action="insert.php" method="post" id="form1"><tr><td align="center"><select id="selectW" name="type"><option value="لم يتم التحديد">اختر النوع</option><option value="دولارات">دولارات</option><option value="أيام + دولارات">أيام + دولارات</option><option value="بطاقات">بطاقات</option><option value="هواتف">هواتف</option><option value="اكسسوارات">اكسسوارات</option><option value="تسديد فواتير">تسديد فواتير</option></select><?php foreach($result5 as $rows){ ?><option value="<?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?>"><?php echo $rows['item_name'] ?></option><?php } ?></td><td align="center"><select id="select_at" name="alfa_touch"><option value="غير محدد">Not Required</option><option value="Alfa">Alfa</option><option value="Touch">Touch</option></select></td><td align="center"><input type="text" id="pay" name="pay"/></td><td align="center"><input type="text" id="facture" name="facture" placeholder="في حال دفع الفواتير عبر omt"/></td><td align="center"><select id="select" name="currency"><option value="9">ليرة</option><option value="10">دولار</option></select></td><td align="center"><input type="submit" id="insert" name="insert" value="اضافة" /></td></tr></form>   <?php $sum = 0;$selectAll = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date_now = :date ORDER BY date_now DESC, time_now DESC"; $stmtAll=$conn->prepare($selectAll); $stmtAll->bindValue(':date', date("y-m-d")); $execAll=$stmtAll->execute(); $result=$stmtAll->fetchAll();?><?php foreach($result as $rows){$sum = $sum + $rows['pay'];//var_Dump($rows) ?><tr><td height="30" align="center"><?php echo $rows['type'] ?></td><td align="center"><?php echo $rows['provider'] ?></td><td align="center" dir="ltr"><?php echo (number_format($rows['pay'], 0, ',', ' ')). ' L.L'?></td><td align="center"><?php echo $rows['facture'] ?></td><td align="center"><form action='delete.php' method="post"><input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" /><input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('هل أنت متأكد؟')" name="delete_sales" value="" /></form></td></tr><?php } ?><tr><th colspan="4" align="center" bgcolor="#666666">المجموع</th><td dir="ltr" bgcolor="#666666" align="center"><?php echo ($sum = number_format($sum, 0, ',', ' ')). ' L.L';?></td></tr></table></div>');
});
});
```

But ...  You need to just enter one table element at a time..  Until the code breaks.

So I'd start with

`$('#YourDivId').append('<div id="section2">');`

Test it.

Then

`$('#YourDivId').append('<div id="section2"><table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">');`

Test it.

And so on, and so forth ..

Comment: Thanks, but their is a missing )

Comment: Actually it's missing a trailing ' ..  I'll fix that